# Connect Bootstrap clickable-row with href link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am dynamically creating a table and want to have every row clickable and link to an URL and open the URL after clicking.

I figured out to create the table and set every row as clickable-row with bootstrap.

```js
        // Table Body
        var tableBody = document.createElement('tbody');
        tableData.forEach(function(rowData) {
            var row = document.createElement('tr');
            var IntegrityURL = "integrity://lanwinsvmks1.eu.adglob.net:8001/im/viewissue?selection=";
            var ReqURL = IntegrityURL.concat(rowData[0]);
            row.setAttribute("class", "clickable-row");
            row.setAttribute("href", ReqURL);
            rowData.forEach(function(cellData) {
                var cell = document.createElement('td');
                var context = getColor(cellData);
                cell.setAttribute("bgcolor",context);
                cell.appendChild(document.createTextNode(cellData));
                row.appendChild(cell);
            });
            tableBody.appendChild(row);
        });
```

I also set up a click function in doc.ready:

```js
    $('#OverviewTable tr').click(function() {
        var href = $(this).find("tr").attr("href");
        if(href) {
            window.location = href;
        }
    });
```

The result in html looks right, but the row is not clickable and the click() function is not called.

**What am I missing?**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try this: *Please comment below if you have any question.*

```js
$('.clickable-tr').on('click', function(){
  var myLink = $(this).attr('href');
  window.location.href = myLink;
});
```

```css
.clickable-tr{
  cursor: pointer;
  background: #eee;
}

table{
  width: 100%;
}

thead tr th{
  text-align: left;
}

tr td{
  padding: 8px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Column1</th>
      <th>Column2</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="clickable-tr" href="https://stackoverflow.com">
      <td>
        Data 1 example
      </td>
      <td>Data 1 Example</td>
    </tr>
    
    <tr class="clickable-tr" href="https://stackoverflow.com">
      <td>
        Data 2 example
      </td>
      <td>Data 2 Example</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

**Update:** *Explanation*

In `js` code, we are targeting the element that has `clickable-tr` class. Then using `$(this)`, we are saying that the only current element/click will be selected. Then using `attr()`, we are getting the current `href` attribute and use to redirect using the `window.location.href`.

Comment: This looks promissing but the function is still not called! I added an a href tag below the tr (beside the td) how do I dynamically add an <a href> ON the tr, like this -> <tr class "clickable-tr a href=URL> </tr>

Comment: What function you are referring to?

Comment: I want to create the table like this:       <td>
        <a href="https://stackoverflow.com">Data 2 example</a>
      </td> or in my case like this:       <tr>
        <a href="https://stackoverflow.com">Data 2 example</a>
      </tr> so that the Click function as you wrote it can find the a tag in the right position

Comment: So you don't want the `<a>` tag? and just the `<tr>` with specified link?

Comment: Yes! How do I write the click function if I do not have an <a> tag in the <tr> just like in my screen shot of the html above.

Comment: Ok. Please check my UPDATE

Comment: @mrpepper Is it working now? Please review my update.

Comment: Thank you! I basically got the syntax right in my own, but the document ready function that included other code did not execute the click function, so I added the click code to another .js file with another docReady and now it works!

Comment: That's great! Glad you got the solution :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try for this:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
   $('#movies tr').each(function(i,e)
   {
      $(e).children('td:not(:last)').click(function()
      {
         //here we are working on a td element, that's why we need
         //to refer to its parent (tr) in order to find the <a> element
         var href = $(this).closest("tr").find("a").attr("href");
         if(href)
         {
            window.location = href;
         }              
      });
   });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

hmm could be that your:

```
var href = $(this).find("tr").attr("href");
```

should be:

```
var href = $(this).attr("href");
```

as 'this' is already the 'tr' element with the href attr